# calculate the sum of selected items in servlet using session tracking

Tags: java, html, session, servlets

i have retrieved my database to Servlet, so that now it looks like this: 
[image]

the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ex.getExpenses().size(); i++) {
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td > " + ex.getExpenses().get(i).getNum()+ "</td>");
        out.println("<td > " + ex.getExpenses().get(i).getPayment() + "</td>");
        out.println("<td > " + ex.getExpenses().get(i).getReceiver() + "</td>");
        out.println("<td > " + ex.getExpenses().get(i).getValue() + "</td>");
        out.println("<td><form ><input name = \"num\" type = \"hidden\" value = \""+ex.getExpenses().get(i).getNum()+"  \">");
        out.println("<input type = \"submit\" value = \"add\">");
        out.println("</form></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");


    }
    out.println("<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><input type = \"submit\" value = \"get the SUM\"></td>");
    out.println("</table>");
```

what else i have to do is using session tracking (and hidden field type which i have "add") write i servlet that will calculate the sum of  chosen values ( like if i press add after value 22 and then after value 5555 it will show the result when clicking "get the sum button" 5577.0).
it looks like adding to shopping cart and then getting the sum of what i want to buy. but i've never done this before, so i'm asking for your help.

i'm still desperately waiting to any help!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought on having the sum on a hidden field in the client side?
Looks easier than using the session.

Comment: well it should calculate the results of chosen values and then retrieve the sum by clicking "get the sum".

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what I guess you want to do is, when someone clicks "add", you need to post the "value" field of your table to the servlet.

Then from your servlet, add this value to the session and re show the form.

When you re show the form you can get the value from the session and display in the JSP if you need to like a shopping cart.

When the same user presses another "add" button, then, again in your servlet, you add the new value to the old session value, and re show the form.

One thing to note - I can see your value field in the table is not within the form tags. Therefore you won't be able to retrieve this value from your servlet.

Have a look at the [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) and [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, i've read the oracle articles, but still i'm stuck. i know that i have to create an object of session that will store all of the selected "add" buttons. `HttpSession session = request.getSession();`. but i can't go any further than this. could you tell me what are my next steps and what am i doing wrong?